# Application compatible to all platforms:PC,smartphones,tablet

Tags: html, user-interface

For an application to be compatible to all platforms PC,mobile,tablets, what are the things to be noted while building the application. Can it be achieved?

I am planning to get a hands on on HTML5, with this application.

So,for a compatible app, only difference will be on the UI or there has to be differences in the back end designing and integration too ?

Expecting an idea based on which I can further explore and learn.

Thanks

Sowmiya

Comment: "App" in what sense? A *web site/app* on your server viewed in a browser on diverse clients? Should it be *optimized* for different device types, or should it just be usable/viewable?

Comment: @deceze yeah.. App on my server viewed on diverse clients.For now,I am looking for 'It should be viewable on all devices'.